# Unexpected output of char arrays in c++

Tags: c++, char

I'm pretty inexperienced in c++, and I wrote the following code to see how characters and strings work.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char asdf[] = "hello";
    char test[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    cout << test;
}
```

I was expected it to output "hello", but instead I got "hellohello", which is really puzzling to me. I did some experimenting:

If I change the asdf to another string of a different length, it outputs "hello" normally.
If I change the amount of characters in test it outputs "hello" normally.

I thought this only happened when the two were the same length, but when I change them both to "hell" it seems to output "hell" normally.

To make things more confusing, when I asked a friend to run this code on their computer, it outputted "hello" and then a random character.

I'm running a fresh install of code blocks on Ubuntu. Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Please try to write a better title, that will be useful for future research.

Comment: Sure, what title would you recommend? I couldn't think of a way to describe the issue succinctly.

Comment: Something like _"Unexpected output of char arrays"_ maybe. Anyways something that describes the situation you meet more clearly and allows others researching to find it.

Comment: You should learn C++ from a book. This would be explained to you within the first couple of chapters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *undefined behaviour*.

Raw `char*` or `char[]` strings in C and C++ must be [NULL-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). That is, the string needs to end with a `'\0'` character. Your `test[5]` does not do that, so the function printing the output continues after the last `o`, because it is still looking for the NULL-termination.

Due to how the strings are stored on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) (the stack usually grows towards *lower* addresses), the next bytes it encounters are those of `asdf[]`, to which you assigned `"hello"`. This is how the memory layout actually looks like, the arrow indicates the direction in which memory addresses (think pointers) increase:

```
      ---->
  +-------------------
  |hellohello\0 ...
  +-------------------
        \_ asdf
   \_ test
```

Now in C++ and C, string literals like `"hello"` are NULL-terminated implicitly, so the compiler writes a hidden `'\0'` behind the end of the string. The output function continues to print the contents of asdf char-by-char until it reaches that hidden `'\0'` and then it stops.

If you were to remove the `asdf`, you would likely see a bit of garbage after the first `hello` and then a segmentation fault. But this is undefined behaviour, because you are reading out of the bounds of the `test` array. This also explains why it behaves differently on different systems: for example, some compilers may decide to lay out the variables in a different order on the stack, so that on your friends system, `test` is actually lower on the stack (remember, lower on the stack means at a higher address):

```
      ---->
  +-------------------
  |hello\0hello ...
  +-------------------
          \_ test
   \_ asdf
```

Now when you print the contents of `test`, it will print `hello` char-by-char, then continue reading the memory until a `\0` is found. The contents of `...` are highly specific to architecture and runtime used, possibly even phase of the moon and time of day (not entirely serious), so that on your friends machine it prints a "random" character and stops then.

You can fix this by adding a `'\0'` or `0` to your `test` array (you will need to change the size to 6). However, using `const char test[] = "hello";` is the sanest way to solve this.

Comment: The answer is good but I'm not sure what you're trying to get at with the note.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Though when I remove the asdf line it seems to display normally. Is this some c++ magic to fix the fact that there's no null terminator?

Comment: @KieronDowie Please check my edit. I’ve added some ASCII-art graphics to show how the memory is laid out. If you remove the ``asdf``, it is similar to the second graphic. The contents of ``...`` may easily start with a NUL character, thus terminating the output.

Answer (score 5):

You have to terminate your `test` array with an ascii 0 char. What happens now is that in memory it is adjacent to your asdf string, so since `test` isn't terminated, the `<<` will just continue until it meets the ascii 0 at the end of `asdf`.

In case you wonder: When filling `asdf`, this ascii 0 is added automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that C style strings need the null character to mark the end of the string.

As you have not put this into the array `test` it will just keep printing characters until it finds one. In you case the array `asdf` happens to follow `test` in memory - but this cannot be guaranteed.

Instead change the code to this:

```
 char test[] = {'h','e','l','l','o', 0};
```

Comment: Wow, fast answer. Thanks a lot, that seemed to be the issue!

Comment: Typo: should be `char test[6]`.

Comment: Thanks - should be `char test[]`

Answer (score 2):

`cout` is printing all characters starting from the beginning of the given address (`test` here, or `&test[0]` in equivalent notation) up to the point where it finds a null terminator. As you haven't put a null terminator into the test array it will continue to print until it accidently finds one in memory. Up from this point it's pretty much undefined behavior what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Last character should be `'\0'` to indicate end of string.

```
 char test[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an overload of `operator<<` for a reference to an array of 5 chars, the array will "decay" to a pointer to char and treated as a C style string by the operator. C style strings are by convention terminated with a 0 char, which your array is lacking. Therefore the operator continues outputting the bytes in memory, interpreting them as printable chars. It just so happens that on the stack, the two arrays were adjacent so that the operator ran into `asdf`'s memory area, outputting those chars and finally encountering the implicit 0 char which is at the end of `"hello"`. If you omit the other declaration it's likely that your program will crash, namely if the next 0 byte comes later than the memory boundary of your program.

It is undefined behavior to access memory outside an object (here: `test`) through a pointer to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Character sequences need a *[null terminator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/)* (`\0`).

```
char asdf[] = "hello"; // OK: String literals have '\0' appended at the end
char test[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'}; // Oops, not null terminated. UB
```

Corrected:

```
char test[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}; // OK
//        ^                         ^^^^
```